# Azure xplat to run a CustomScriptExtension in a Windows VM

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, bootstrapping, azure-xplat-cli

I am creating Windows VMs from the azure xplat cli, using the following command:

```
azure network vnet create --location "East US" testnet
azure vm create --vm-name xplattest3 --location "East US" --virtual-network-name testnet --rdp 3389 xplattest3 ad072bd3082149369c449ba5832401ae__Windows-Server-Remote-Desktop-Session-Host-on-Windows-Server-2012-R2-20150828-0350 username SAFEpassword!
```

After the Windows VM is created I would like to execute a powershell script to configure the server. As far I understand, this is done by executing a CustomScriptExtension.

I found several examples for PowerShell but no examples for Xplat cli.

I would like, for example, to run the following [HelloWorld PowerShell script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tk421/8b7dd37145eaa8f82e2f/raw/36c11aafd3f5d6b4af97aab9ef5303d80e8ab29b/azureCustomScriptExtensionTest):

```
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\HelloWorld
```

After reading documentation I should be able to run a CustomExtensionScript by executing something like this (**the following command does not work**):

```
azure vm extension set xplattest3 CustomScriptExtension Microsoft.Compute 1.4 -i '{"URI":["https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tk421/8b7dd37145eaa8f82e2f/raw/36c11aafd3f5d6b4af97aab9ef5303d80e8ab29b/azureCustomScriptExtensionTest"] }'
```

I think that the problem is the parameter `-i`. I have not been able to find an example on Internet. There are some references and documentation such as [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn781373.aspx) and [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/1539), but no examples.

Therefore, my question: How to execute a `PowerShell` script after creating a Windows VM in Azure using the `xplat cli` ?

Please note that the my current approach is a `CustomScriptExtension`, but *anything* that allows to bootstrap a configuration script will be considered!

**EDIT** How do I know it is failing ?

After I run the command `azure vm extension ...`:

1. `xplat cli` confirms that the command has been executed properly.
2. As per [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn781373.aspx), the folder `C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\` is created, but there is no script downloaded to `C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\{version-number}\Downloads\{iteration}`
3. The folder `C:\HelloWorld` is not created, which means that the contents of the script has not been executed.
4. I cannot find any sort of logs or a trace to know what happened. Does anyone knows where can I find this information ?

Comment: It might help if you include why it's not working. Are you getting an error when you make the call via the cli tool, or is the extension being added and the script itself isn't running?

Comment: @MikeWo the description has been updated. The extension is added, the script is not running, and I can't find any sort of logs or trace of why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters (The Json) that I used after reading the MSDN documentation were not correct. However, you can get clues of the correct parameters by reading the C# code.

And the final command is:

```
azure vm extension set xplattest3 CustomScriptExtension Microsoft.Compute 1.4 -i '{"fileUris":["https://macstoragetest.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainername/createFolder.ps1"], "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file createFolder.ps1" }'
```

This command successfully creates the `C:\HelloWorld` directory.

NOTE: I decided to upload the script to Azure as I [read in a post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f409fd49-82eb-4982-b416-6914d65d6813/customscriptextension-fileuri?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) and in the documentation that is mandatory. However I just made a test to download the original script from Github and it is working fine, so I guess that the documentation is a bit outdated.

**EDIT**: I created an detailed article that explains [how to provision windows servers with xplat-cli in Azure](http://blog.manageacloud.com/entry/azure-provision-windows-automatically).